# Unlocking an iPhone with iOS 7.0.4 using SAM (Subscriber Artificial Module)

Tags: iphone, unlock

I want to unlock my iPhone with [a utility called SAM, or Subscriber Artificial Module](http://www.maketecheasier.com/hactivate-your-iphone-with-subscriber-artificial-module-sam/).

I saved my activation ticket and used it to unlock my iPhone 4 running iOS 5.1.1.

A few days ago I replaced my old iPhone at an Apple Store an they gave me a new iPhone 4 with iOS 6.1.3.

I installed the update to iOS 7.0.4.

Is it possible to put my SAM activation ticket back on this new iPhone?

I have the original SIM card and the ticket which I have used when SAM came out in April 2013,  but I can't put it back on this new iPhone.

I'm wondering if I can use the SAM ticket and original SIM card in a different iPhone 4.

Comment: What is "Sam"? Please explain.

Comment: @WheatWilliams [Subscriber Artificial Module](http://www.bingner.com/SAM.html)